# Javascript how to compare two arrays and get the values which were closest to each other

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
let arr1 = [6, 10, 7, 7] 
let arr2 = [6, 16, 20, 9]
```

Each value in `arr1` represents the score of a question, where each value in `arr2` represents the max score of the question. So the values are kind of connected. For example question 1 the score was 6 where the max score was also 6, question 2 gave 10 points where the max score could have been 16 etc.

Now I want to compare the values and get the 3 values, which were closest to each other. So in this case it would question 1: 6 out of 6 (0 difference), question 2: 10 out of 16 (difference of 6) and question 4: 7 out of 9 (difference of 2) and maybe sort them by difference?

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: The items which are closest to each other are not determined by the minimum difference but by the quotient which is closest/equal to the maximum value of 1.

Comment: The score difference of _"`1` out of `2`"_ is `1`. But _"`7` out of `9`"_ with a difference of `2` has the better performance ... roughly 78% (`7 / 9`) versus 50% (`1 / 2`).

Comment: @ST80 ... Regarding all the provided answers / approaches / solutions are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new array with the info in arr1, arr2 and also the difference. If you do that, sorting and selecting the top 3 elements become rather trivial:

```
let arr1 = [6, 10, 7, 7] 
let arr2 = [6, 16, 20, 9]

// create a new array with an object for each pair in arr1 and arr2
let zipped = []
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    zipped.push({
        score: arr1[i],
        max: arr2[i],
        diff: arr2[i] - arr1[i]
    })
}

// sort the array by diff
zipped.sort((a, b) => a.diff - b.diff)

// print out the first 3 elements
console.log(zipped.slice(0, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the above comment ...

> *"The items which are closest to each other are not determined by the minimum difference but by the quotient which is closest/equal to the maximum value of 1."*

... thus, one could choose a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach which creates a rated score list by creating and collecting rated score items from the corresponding values of each array, the one with the scores achieved and the one with the achievable scores.

Sorting then becomes a piece of cake since every rated score item does feature following properties ... `achieved`, `achievable`, `scoreDelta` and `rating`. The advice is to sort by a descending `rating`. But of cause the OP can always sort by an ascending `scoreDelta`.

```js
function createAndCollectRatedScoreItem({ achievables, result }, achieved, idx) {
  const achievable = achievables[idx];
  result.push({
    rating: achieved / achievable,
    achieved,
    achievable,
    scoreDelta: achievable - achieved,
  });
  return { achievables, result };
}
const achievedScoreList = [6, 10, 7, 7, 1];
const achievableScoreList = [6, 16, 20, 9, 2];

const ratedScoreList = achievedScoreList
  .reduce(
    createAndCollectRatedScoreItem,
    { achievables: achievableScoreList, result: [] }
  )
  .result
  .sort((a, b) => b.rating - a.rating);
 
const bestRatedScoreTripple = ratedScoreList.slice(0, 3);

console.log({ ratedScoreList, bestRatedScoreTripple });
console.log(
  'rated score list sorted by ascending score delta ...',
  ratedScoreList.sort((a, b) => a.scoreDelta - b.scoreDelta)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach which enables re-usable code utilizes [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in combination with its 2nd [`thisArg` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters).

The implementation of the above code example then changes slightly to ...

```js
function createRatedScoreItemFromBoundAchievableScores(achieved, idx) {
  const achievable = this[idx];
  return {
    rating: achieved / achievable,
    achieved,
    achievable,
    scoreDelta: achievable - achieved,
  }
}
const achievedScoreList = [6, 10, 7, 7, 1];
const achievableScoreList = [6, 16, 20, 9, 2];

const ratedScoreList = achievedScoreList
  .map(
    createRatedScoreItemFromBoundAchievableScores,
    achievableScoreList
  )
  .sort((a, b) => b.rating - a.rating);
 
const bestRatedScoreTripple = ratedScoreList.slice(0, 3);

console.log({ ratedScoreList, bestRatedScoreTripple });
console.log(
  'rated score list sorted by ascending score delta ...',
  ratedScoreList.sort((a, b) => a.scoreDelta - b.scoreDelta)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by combining all relevant data for each question together in one object. Instead of two separate arrays we could have one combined array. Depending on the info you need after the operation you might want to include/omit certain info in this object.

If you need the index of the question after the operation, you'll probably want to store it ahead of time. If you want to sort based on the difference between the max score and actual score, it's faster to calculate this ahead of time.

A fairly easy way to collect your data would be to use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const combined = arr1.map((score, index) => {
  const max   = arr2[index];
  const diff  = max - score;
  const ratio = score / max;
  return { score, max, index, diff, ratio };
});
```

After collecting the necessary data you can [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) your array based on your criteria. For example:

```
combined.sort((a, b) => a.diff - b.diff);
```

After sorting the data you can grab the first 3 elements using. [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```
// Takes element 0 up to but not including 3 and put them in a new array.
const result = combined.slice(0, 3);
console.log(result);
```

Alternatively you could also use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to mutate `combined`, removing all unwanted elements.

```
// Removes all elements starting at element 3.
combined.splice(3);
console.log(combined);
```

```js
const actualScores = [6, 10,  7, 7];
const maxScores    = [6, 16, 20, 9];

const scores = actualScores.map((score, index) => {
  const max   = maxScores[index];
  const diff  = max - score;
  const ratio = score / max;
  return { score, max, index, diff, ratio };
});

// sort by ratio descending
scores.sort((a, b) => b.ratio - a.ratio);
// take elements 0-3 (excluding) from `scores`
const scoresA = scores.slice(0, 3);

// sort by diff ascending
scores.sort((a, b) => a.diff - b.diff);
// take elements 0-3 (excluding) from `scores`
const scoresB = scores.slice(0, 3);

// remove all elements with index 3 or higher
scores.splice(3)

console.log("first 3 scores ordered by ratio descending",        scoresA);
console.log("first 3 scores ordered by diff ascending (slice)",  scoresB);
console.log("first 3 scores ordered by diff ascending (splice)", scores);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a third array diff[] containing the difference between arr2 and arr1:

```
let diff = [];
arr2.forEach( (o, i) => diff.push(o-arr1[i]) );
```

Comment: `[0, 6, 13, 2]` is the `diff` result of the above approach. According to the OP, the result should have been an array with the 3 first best rated scores and not an array of just differences of all related scores. Thus the OP was looking for a result maybe similar to `[[6, 6], [7, 9], [10, 16]]` which the OP was describing with these words ... _"Now I want to ... get the 3 values, which were closest to each other. So in this case it would [be] ... 6 out of 6 (0 difference), ... 10 out of 16 (difference of 6) and ... 7 out of 9 (difference of 2) and maybe sort them by difference?"_

Comment: it wasn't clear to me. Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score -1):

```
let arr1 = [6, 10, 7, 7] 
let arr2 = [6, 16, 20, 9]

function difference(a,b) {
 const diff = [];
 for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  diff[i] = b[i]-a[i];
 }
 return diff;
}

console.log(difference(arr1,arr2).sort((a,b) => a-b).slice(0,3))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.